# key error using font spec to chose basic font.

Tags: fontspec

I am using lualatex to compile a document (I have to use this compiler due to other packages I need). I am trying to change the font for just the notes. My code so far

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\text{
\newfontfamily\textnote[1]{{Arial}}
\text{ \textnote{This is a note.} }
}
```

I think Latex can find the font (because it doesnt throw a font not found error. Instead I get:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/key-unknown"
! 
! The key 'fontspec-opentype/1' is unknown and is being ignored.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

I have verified that Arial exists as a font (I can find it in Font Book and can use it in word). Does anyone have any ideas about how I could fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're using the wrong syntax. What's precisely your aim?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I am trying to change the font of just one word (ie whole document is one font, a single word is in Wingdings font). I have tried to follow examples and guides and this is where I got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax. Also, `\newfontfamily` should be in the preamble, before `\begin{document}`.

Sorry, but I don't have Windings, so the example uses a different symbol font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\windings{MarVoSym} % I don't have Windings in OT format
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textwingdings}{\normalfont\windings}

\begin{document}

text \textwingdings{text} text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `\newfontfamily` command does not have the same syntax as (say) `\newcommand`.

The optional argument to `\newfontfamily` is a comma-separated list of Open Type font features. Prior to that optional argument, is a mandatory argument that gives the font a command name. In your case, you probably do not need any Open Type features. So:

```
\newfontfamily\myarial{Arial}
```

That provides the command name `\myarial` which can be used anywhere in the document. To make it the normal font (if that is what you wish to do) then place the command `\myarial` before anything else in the document body.

Otherwise, a local section of text would be like this:

```
{\myarial Some text.}
```

If you wish to select Open Type features, you could do something like this:

```
\newfontfamily\myfunnyarial[Numbers=OldStyle]{Arial}
```

That assumes that the font actually has the specified feature. If not, no harm done.